# Indexes on text columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I need an index on some text columns to increase spped of queries. I not really sure whether I can use FTS or not. I have in my column something like that:
34565A43B2423FRR34AQ and I am searching in that way:

```
WHERE column ~* '5A43B'
```

and I'm expecting that this value will be found. But the table is big (about million rows) and the time is not efficient. What kind of index I can use?

Comment: It is important to notice that I have to use ~* operator because in search interface people can use regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTS won't work for this, a string like this can't be parsed into tokens. There is an extension that can do the trick: [wildspeed](http://www.sigaev.ru/cvsweb/cvsweb.cgi/wildspeed/README.wildspeed?rev=HEAD;content-type=text/plain). You have to install this module in the database before you can use it. The index might be very large, but it can also be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your query by changing POSIX regular expression to LIKE/ILIKE, you can use 
[pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) extension.

Such as:

```
WHERE column ~~* '%5A43B%'
```